# Access Denied for FBA Users - IIS7 virtual directory

Tags: sharepoint, iis, virtual-directory

I have SharePoint installed on my machine Machine1. We are having a file server Machine2 for deploying our asp pages. It is going to be 1000s of files, thats why we have this separate file server.

The sharepoint site is FBA authentication enabled.

The problem i am facing is FBA authenticated users can't able to view the asp page which is in the shared folder. But it is working for anonymous users.

I have shared the folder by providing read permission to "Everyone, anonymous access, authenticated users, applicationpool owner". In the security tab of folder's properties window also i given read permission for the above mentioned users.

The reason why anonymous users able to view the pages is, in IIS7 for anonymous authentication users i set run with "ApplicationIdentity", may be that is the reason why anonym user able to view.

Did anyone faced this issue? I just need to allow the FBA users to browse the pages.

Comment: Did you check authorization configuration for the specified path to pages at the Web.Config relative to WebApplicaiton ?
Did you check SafeControls for the custom path wich contains your pages?

Comment: safecontrols are fine. thats why i am able to view the page as an anonymous user. in authorization in IIS has been enabled for FBA, anonymous, basic and windows authentication. in web.config, there is no deny tag used. Anyhow it has to be working, so i used <allow users="*" /> right now.